# (TS) Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server'

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-2.0, typescript2.0

While i'm developing my Asp.net Core 2 / Angular 5 app.I have received the following error.

> > (TS) Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server'.

Here i have attached the screenshot that the error was generated.
[image]

Here i have add package.json file as well.

```
  {
  "name": "ASPCoreWithAngular",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "karma start ClientApp/test/karma.conf.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/common": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/core": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/forms": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/http": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/platform-server": "4.2.5",
    "@angular/router": "4.2.5",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "1.5.0",
    "@types/chai": "4.0.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.53",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.13.0",
    "angular2-router-loader": "0.3.5",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "aspnet-prerendering": "^3.0.1",
    "aspnet-webpack": "^2.0.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "3.3.7",
    "chai": "4.0.2",
    "css": "2.2.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.4",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.3",
    "event-source-polyfill": "0.0.9",
    "expose-loader": "0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.2",
    "file-loader": "0.11.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "2.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.4",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "json-loader": "0.5.4",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "preboot": "4.5.2",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "5.4.2",
    "style-loader": "0.18.2",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "typescript": "2.4.1",
    "url-loader": "0.5.9",
    "webpack": "2.5.1",
    "webpack-hot-middleware": "2.18.2",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.12"
  }
}
```

Can anyone give me a solution to solve this issue. ?

Comment: can you please share your package.json file ?

Comment: @wessamsalah OP updated.

Comment: did u try to run ->  npm i 
in your console ?

Comment: I have restore package.json file adn problem SOLVED.

Comment: same way , Good (Y)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `npm i @angular/platform-browser` to install it manually.
This is how I solved the issue on my side.

PS: please use `--save` flag to save it like this `npm i --save @angular/platform-browser` to

Comment: It should be `npm i --save @angular/platform-server`

Answer (score 4):

Please run this

```
npm i --save @angular/platform-server
```

on the cli

Answer (score 2):

Use npm i --save @angular/platform-server to install it

Answer (score 1):

i'm using angular 13 and installed angular universal uning:
ng add @nguniversal/express-engine

encountered similar issue:
'Cannot find module '@angular/platform-server' or its corresponding type declarations.ts(2307)'

had to manually install and save this package:

npm i --save @angular/platform-browser